# If $A^2$ is diagonalizable then A is also...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I tried to dis/prove the following:

A is a 2x2 complex matrix

1) If $A^2$ is diag. then $A$ is also.

I mostly tried using $P^{-1} A^2 P = D$ and found out that:

$D=P^{-1} A PP^{-1} A P = \sqrt{D}\sqrt{D}$

I don't think it makes sense though

I also tried using 
$A={%
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
    \end{bmatrix}%
  }\ $ and to make my life easier I set c=0 to work only on triangular matrices, but I'm not sure I'd obtain a general result.

2) if $A$ is invertible and $A^2$ is diag., then A is also diag.

3) if $A^{-1}$ is diag. then A is also.

$P^{-1} A^{-1} P = D$

$A$ is invertible so $D$ is. I take the $^{-1}$ of both sides to prove.

I need some help, thank you...

Comment: Do you know Jordan's theorem?

Comment: Which do you mean? I have only heard about jordan form of matrices, but we have not studied it.

Comment: Think of a non-zero matrix whose square is zero.

Comment: Ok, A=[ [0 a] [0 0] ], $A^2=0$. The 0 matrix is diag. (?) but A is not (if $a\neq 0$). So 1) is disproved. Right?

Comment: For a matrix in Jordan normal form, these should all be fairly easy.

Comment: Have you ever tried rotation matrices?